# Insert PDF into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf

I would like to insert a PDF file into SQL Server.

I tried 2 different queries but still getting the same error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\filename.pdf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

My code:

```
INSERT INTO [Testing].[dbo].[table00](FileContent) 
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\filename.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) as TheFile

INSERT INTO [Testing].[dbo].[table00](FileContent, Blob) 
    SELECT 0, * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\filename.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

Any advice? How to solve this error? Thanks!

Background:

I am trying to insert a PDF file into this particular column `FileContent` with a datatype of Image in my table `testing.dbo.table00`.

Comment: Is the MSSQL remote or local? The file path will be evaluated locally for the MSSQL server, it can't access your dev machine!

Comment: Everything is evaluated in the context of the sql server (windows) service, not the sql management studio interface. The security context under which the service is executing also needs permissions to the location even if it were local.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Matten, thanks for your input. The MSSQL I'm using is a remote server. I have tried loading the pdf on the remote server as well but I am still getting the same error as to how I attempted to load the file locally.

Comment: @Igor thanks! I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the highlights, this is very helpful!! However I will still be loading the pdf into the DB as image for the time being. :)

Comment: On the remote server, does the Windows account that SQL Server is being run under have access to the PDF file? (If you right-click on the file, choose properties, security, advanced, then check effective access for the SQL Server account, does that account have access to the file?)

Comment: @BenGribaudo Hi Ben, thanks!! I've managed to load the file in after following your steps in adding permission to SQL Server account.

Comment: Hi, Can I check if the same query can be used to upload a .docx file into SQL? I would like to store a word document into my database as ntext. @BenGribaudo

Comment: Sure, you can check that!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the file doesn't exist or SQL Server doesn't have permission to access it.

Keep in mind that the path passed to `OPENROWSET BULK` is relative to the SQL Server, **not** to the computer from which you're executing the query (unless that computer is the SQL Server). So, in your case, `C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\filename.pdf` must exist **on the SQL Server** in order for your query to succeed.

If the file exists on the server and you still receive this error, it's possible that SQL Server does not have permission to access to the file. To check this, right-click on the file, choose properties, security, advanced, then check effective access for the SQL Server account. If the account does not have rights to access the file, assign the needed permissions.